# Posso usar a tag <figcaption> sem usar o <figure>?

Tags: html, html5, semântica

Quero colocar legendas nas minhas fotos e gostaria de saber se eu posso usar a tag `<figcaption>` sem precisar usá-la dentro da *tag* `<figure>`?

```
<img src="_fotos/imagem-2.jpg" alt="" title="">
<figcaption>legenda da foto...</figcaption>
```

Comment: Não. O elemento `<figcaption>` deve, obrigatoriamente, possuir um elemento `<figure>` como pai. Qual o problema de utilizá-lo?

Comment: _"Permitted parents: A <figure> element; the <figcaption> element must be its first or last child."_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption - Ler a documentação é sempre uma boa.

Comment: na verdade não há problema em usa-lo. só fiquei na duvida, por que se pudesse usa-lo sem a tag figure acho que seria mais pratico

Comment: Sem a tag figure como pai figcaption perde o valor semântico, nesse casso use a tag `<small>` ou `<aside>`

Comment: @hugocsl como usar a tag <small> e <aside>  da maneira que você ta falando ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme dito no comentário não use apenas a tag `<figcaption>` sem a tag `<figure>` antes. `<figcaption>` deve ser filho (estar dentro) de `<figure>` ou vai quebrar a ordem semântica.

> The HTML `<figcaption>` element represents a caption or a legend
>   associated with a figure or an illustration described by the rest of
>   the data of the `<figure>` element which is its immediate ancestor.

*"O elemento HTML `<figcaption>` representa uma legenda ou uma legenda associada a uma figura ou uma ilustração descrita pelo restante dos dados do elemento `<figure>` que é seu ancestral imediato."*

Documentação Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption

---

## Tag `<small>`

Se vc quer fazer uma legenda com os direitos autorais para sua imagem de forma um pouco mais semântica vc pode usar a tag `<small>`

```
<small>legenda da foto...</small>
```

Link documentação Mozilla tag small: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/small

> In HTML5, this element is repurposed to represent side-comments and
>   small print, including copyright and legal text, independent of its
>   styled presentation.

*"Em HTML5, esse elemento é redefinido para representar comentários secundários e letras pequenas, incluindo direitos autorais e texto jurídico, independentemente de sua apresentação estilizada."*

---

## Tag `<aside>`

Ou também pode usar a tag `<aside>` apesar da ressalva que vc pode ler abaixo. *Aside é um conteúdo indireto relacionado ao conteúdo principal, então se a imagem faz parte do foco do assunto use `<small>`, mas se o texto da imagem for apenas algo secundário e não diretamente ligado ao assunto principal do qual a imagem faz parte ai talvez o `aside` lhe sirva. Tente entender como o leitor de tela vai ler o texto e se esse texto deve ser um `<small>` ou `<aside>`*

```
<aside>legenda da foto...</aside>
```

Documentação da Mizilla sobre a tag aside: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside

> The HTML `<aside>` element represents a portion of a document whose
>   content is only indirectly related to the document's main content.

*"O elemento HTML `<aside>` representa uma parte de um documento cujo conteúdo está apenas indiretamente relacionado ao conteúdo principal do documento."*

---

Existe ainda a opção de usar a tag `<details>` mas parece que os browsers ainda não dão muito suporte para ela. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

**OBS:** E o principal, não se esqueça de colocar o atributo `alt=""` na sua tag de `img` e colocar uma descrição completa. O `Alt` é fundamental para os leitores de tela!